# Can Buddhist accept prayers from other religions?

Tags: doubt

Subject refers, can a Buddhist accepts prayer from other religion say Muslim or Christian? I understand the answer is yes.

Comment: What does it mean to "accept".  Simply refraining from saying "I do not accept your prayers"? If so, yes. Just saying "Thanks" or being silent is not  in conflict with Dharma practice.

Answer (score 1):

We do not pray for religion. We pray for people. People of all kinds. No discrimination. If Christian or Hindu or Muslim prays for us then we should accept it gratefully...

Answer (score 1):

Prayer is nothing more than well wishing with some external mythical locus as a framework. That framework only has meaning to the adherents of that same framework.

To everyone else it's just well wishing.
The intention of the prayer is what's important, not the framework within which it was uttered.

If a person means well with their intentions it matters not how they vocalise that intention.

We can certainly "accept" someone's intentions without any reference to their personal belief framework.